# How to use Bootstrape in breeze in laravel 9 and vite

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, breeze, vite

I want to make a project in Laravel 9 using breeze, but i can not see any way to include bootstrap in my project. there are some ways like jetstrap package, but it replaces complete vue system with blade files, which i dont want to do.

Please can you tell me a simple way to use bootstrap with breeze (laravel 9 + vite)

i am expecting a good solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Breeze is made with **tailwind** not Bootstrap.
If u want an auth/login with bootstrap u can use **laravel/ui**

https://github.com/laravel/ui